# Obter versão do App na Play Store

Tags: android

Estou tentando pegar a versão do  APP na Play Store para comparar com a Versão instalada e poder forçar a atualização caso do dispositivo seja inferior da Loja, mas não estou conseguindo pegar a versão da Loja. Uso eclipse. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o que é indicado na própria documentação https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates

Para instalar pode importar a biblioteca Play Core para o projeto Android como uma dependência do Gradle, no seu **`build.grandle`**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'
    ...
}
```

A biblioteca **Play Core KTX** é opcional e fornece versões de [**Kotlin coroutines**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-guide.html) para chamadas de métodos assíncronas na biblioteca normal do Play Core, além de outras extensões úteis que usam as APIs mais idiomáticas do Kotlin, então se usa Java não precisa instalar essa biblioteca.

Em Java:

```
AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context);

Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
    // Faz o que deseja aqui, inclusive forçar iniciar o update
    }
});
```

Mas pode usar também `AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE`, o que depende da necessidade.

Em **Kotlin** será:

```
val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context)
val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo

appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
    ) {
        // Faz o que deseja aqui, inclusive forçar iniciar o update
    }
}
```

Você pode exibir uma mensagem dentro da IF, ou um alerta, ou fechar o app, ou abrir a playstore ou então usar diretamente o `appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult()`, também como é dito na documentação https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#start_update, exemplo em Java:

```
if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
        ) {

    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
        appUpdateInfo,
        AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
        this,
        MEU_CODIGO_REQUISICAO);
}
```

Em **Kotlin**:

```
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
    ) {
    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
        appUpdateInfo,
        AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
        this,
        MEU_CODIGO_REQUISICAO)
}
```

Note que o `MEU_CODIGO_REQUISICAO` não é um código "nativo", é um valor que você pode setar para poder usar um callback para saber se o UPDATE falhou, o que você pode adicionar no seu activity para monitorar baseado nesse código (que pode ser uma constante), em **Java** o valor do código de requisição pode ficar assim:

```
private static final int MEU_CODIGO_REQUISICAO = 90002;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == MEU_CODIGO_REQUISICAO && resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
    // Se falhou e é sobre o seu update você pode fazer o que desejar, por exemplo um "alert" que diga que isso falhou
  }
}
```

Em **Kotlin** a constante pode ser algo como:

```
// Um valor qualquer
const val MEU_CODIGO_REQUISICAO = 90002
```

E o callback:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    if (requestCode == MEU_CODIGO_REQUISICAO && resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        // Se falhou e é sobre o seu update
    }
}
```

Comment: Meu problema está em não conseguir baixar a biblioteca com.google.android.play para o Eclipse.

Comment: Olá @Trapé. Resposta editada.

Comment: @Trapé conseguiu baixar a biblioteca usando o Gradle como mostrei na resposta? Se não me avisa, para poder te ajudar.